# create csv that will only add one header for each line

Tags: python

I have a file that looks like this

```
a:1
a:2
a:3
b:1
b:2
b:2
```

and I would like it to take the the a and b portion of the file and add it as the first column and and the number below, like this.

```
a b
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you have a typo.  Shouldn't the last line of your input file be: `b:3` ?  Otherwise, I don't know how you could derive `3 3` as the last line of your output file.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV (Comma Separated File) should have commas in it, so the output should have commas instead of space-separators.

I recommend writing your code in two parts:  The first part should read the input; the second should write out the output.

If your input looks like this:

```
a:1
a:2
a:3
b:1
b:2
b:2
c:7
```

you can read in the input like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Usage:  python3 scripy.py < input.txt > output.csv

import sys

# Loop through all the input lines and put the values in
# a list according to their category:
categoryList = {}  # key => category, value => list of values
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    category, value = line.split(':')
    if category not in categoryList:
        categoryList[category] = []
    categoryList[category].append(value)

# print(categoryList)  # debug line
# Debug line prints:  {'a': ['1', '2', '3'], 'b': ['1', '2', '2']}
```

This will read in all your data into a categoryList dict.  It's a dict that contains the categories (the letters) as keys, and contains lists (of numbers) as the values.  Once you have all the data held in that dict, you can output it.

Outputting involves getting a list of categories (the letters, in your example case) so that they can be written out first as your header:

```
# Get the list of categories:
categories = sorted(categoryList.keys())
assert categories, 'No categories found!'  # sanity check
```

From here, you can use Python's nice *csv* module to output the header and then the rest of the lines.  When outputting the main data, we can use an outer loop to loop through the *nth* entries of each category, then we can use an inner loop to loop through every category:

```
import csv
csvWriter = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

# Output the categories as the CSV header:
csvWriter.writerow(categories)

# Now output the values we just gathered as
# Comma Separated Values:
i = 0  # the index into an individual category list
while True:
    values = []
    for category in categories:
        try:
            values.append(categoryList[category][i])
        except IndexError:
            values.append('')  # no value, so use an empty string
    if len(''.join(values)) == 0:
        break  # we've run out of categories that contain input
    csvWriter.writerow(values)
    i += 1  # increment index for the next time through the loop
```

If you don't want to use Python's *csv* module, you will still need to figure out how to group the entries in the category together.  And if all you have is simple output (where none of the entries contain quotes, newlines, or commas), you can get away with manually writing out the output.

You could use something like this to output your values:

```
# Output the categories as the CSV header:
print(','.join(categories))

# Now output the values we just gathered as
# Comma Separated Values:
i = 0  # the index into an individual category list
while True:
    values = []
    for category in categories:
        try:
            values.append(categoryList[category][i])
        except IndexError:
            values.append('')  # no value, so use an empty string
    if len(''.join(values)) == 0:
        break  # we've run out of categories that contain input
    print(','.join(values))
    i += 1  # increment index for the next time through the loop
```

This will print out:

```
a,b,c
1,1,7
2,2,
3,2,
```

It does this by looping through all the list entries (the outer loop), and then looping through all the categories (the inner loop), and then printing out the values joined together by commas.

If you don't want the commas in your output, then you're technically not looking for CSV (Comma Separated Value) output.  Still, in that case, it should be easy to modify the code to get what you want.

But if you have more complicated output (that is, values that have quotes, commas, and newlines in it) you should strongly consider using the *csv* module to output your data.  Otherwise, you'll spend lots of time trying to fix obscure bugs with odd input that the *csv* module already handles.

Comment: This is only getting the first value of each category for the csv, I'm fairly new to python and this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: @rufione, I don't understand when you say it's only getting the first value of each category.  The output of the code I gave you shows three lines after the header, so it seems to me it's getting all three values.  Could it be that in the input data you're using, there's a category with only one entry?  If so, the Python script I wrote would detect that the second entry is not complete, and so end its output.

Comment: I think that is probably whats going on.

Comment: Can you provide a slightly bigger set of input data? One that better reflects what you're working with?

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm glad I could be of help!  In the future, remember to provide a set of example input that covers everything (not just part of) what you need.  Otherwise, people will create code that can handle the given input, but won't necessarily handle the sets you didn't specify (and you really can't blame them for that).